# Number of values lying in a specified range

Tags: python, unix, pandas, awk

I have a data frame like the one below:

```
NC_011163.1:1
NC_011163.1:22
NC_011163.1:44
NC_011163.1:65
NC_011163.1:73
NC_011163.1:87
NC_011163.1:104
NC_011163.1:130
NC_011163.1:151
NC_011163.1:172
NC_011163.1:194
NC_011163.1:210
NC_011163.1:235
NC_011163.1:255
NC_011163.1:295
NC_011163.1:320
NC_011163.1:445
NC_011163.1:520
```

I would like to scan the data frame using a window of 210 and count number of values lying in every 210 window.

Desired output:

```
output: Values 
NC_011163.1:1-210   12
NC_011163.1:211-420 4
NC_011163.1:421-630 2
```

I'd greatly appreciate your inputs to solve this problem.

Thanks

V

Comment: [edit] your question to include what you have tried so far.

Comment: as is now, this lacks your attempts. Please show them after giving a good read to [ask].

Comment: And by windows of 210 you mean 210 samples, not values 1-210 after the colon (:)?

Comment: @James looks like values given the result of 12...

Comment: where is the data stored? what's the format of the file? You can just use `split(':')[1]` to get the value you want to compare and then find the first integer `x` for which `x * 210 > value`. If for example, `x = 1` the value belongs in class 1 or in other words in `1-210` range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=":"; OFS="\t"; endOfRange=210 }
{
    key = $1
    bucket = int((($2-1)/endOfRange)+1)
    cnt[bucket]++
    maxBucket = (bucket > maxBucket ? bucket : maxBucket)
}
END {
    for (bucket=1; bucket<=maxBucket; bucket++) {
        print key ":" ((bucket-1)*endOfRange)+1 "-" bucket*endOfRange, cnt[bucket]+0
    }
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
NC_011163.1:1-210       12
NC_011163.1:211-420     4
NC_011163.1:421-630     2
```

Note that this will work even if you have some ranges with no values in your input data (it will print the range with a count of zero) and it will always print the ranges in numerical order (output order when using the `in` operator is "random"):

```
$ cat file
NC_011163.1:1
NC_011163.1:22
NC_011163.1:520

$ awk -f tst.awk file
NC_011163.1:1-210       2
NC_011163.1:211-420     0
NC_011163.1:421-630     1
```

Comment: I would like your input on how to modify the code if there are multiple keys in a file (eg., NC_011163.1, NC_011164.1, NC_011166.1 etc.,). Thanks

Comment: Make `cnt` an array, e,g, `cnt[key]++`.

Answer (score 2):

If you use python and [Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/), you can do:

with your data in a dataframe `df`:

```
             NC    N
0   NC_011163.1    1
1   NC_011163.1   22
2   NC_011163.1   44
3   NC_011163.1   65
4   NC_011163.1   73
5   NC_011163.1   87
6   NC_011163.1  104
7   NC_011163.1  130
8   NC_011163.1  151
9   NC_011163.1  172
10  NC_011163.1  194
11  NC_011163.1  210
12  NC_011163.1  235
13  NC_011163.1  255
14  NC_011163.1  295
15  NC_011163.1  320
16  NC_011163.1  445
17  NC_011163.1  520

df.groupby([df.NC, pd.cut(df.N, range(0,631,210))]).count()
                         N
NC          N             
NC_011163.1 (0, 210]    12
            (210, 420]   4
            (420, 630]   2
```

Where:

- `pd.cut(df.N, range(0, 631, 210))` returns in which bins are the value in the column `N`. bins are defined by the range, which creates 3 bins: `[0, 210, 420, 630]`.
- Then you groupby on:

  - the NC number (so it matches your output but here is useless as there is only one group, but I guess you'll have other chromosomes, hence it will perform the operation per chromosome)
  - the bins you've just made
- `count` the number of element in each group.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -v t=210 'BEGIN{FS=":";t++}{++a[int($2/t)]}
   END{for(x in a){printf "%s:%s\t%d\n",$1,t*x"-"(x+1)*t,a[x]}}' file
```

will give this output:

```
NC_011163.1:0-211       12
NC_011163.1:211-422     4
NC_011163.1:422-633     2
```

- You don't need to find out what is the max value, how many sections/ranges you have in result. This command does it for you.
- The codes are easy to understand too I think, most codes are for the output format.

Comment: the output of range `x-y` has problem.. e.g. `211-422` should be `211-420` but I think you can fix it on your own. The key is you got the idea, how to calculate the range and the count.

Comment: You should mention that not all awks will preserve `$1` in the END section and that it's just coincidence that the output order is as desired.